# How to play play sound without user's intervention using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, signalr

I am working on the Asp.Net MVC Web application. I am calling one javascript method using SignalR, and in this method, I am trying to play sound from some backend event, but it doesn't play if I am not on the same browser tab or my browser is minimized just like the youtube video  ( you click on the youtube video link, it will not play until and unless you bring that screen foreground once).

```
<audio id="audioId" autoplay loop>
    <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

code to play the audio `audioId.play();`

It works fine if I am on the screen, but not if the screen is minimized or in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without html markup.

But keep in mind that **audio file need to be load before the user minimize the screen**. And the user have to interact (scroll, click, or any touch or click event) with document before minimize (as any autoplay feature).

Or you gonna have following error:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Take a look to google about autoplay: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

<del>**So if you try something like that it's will not work:**</del>

```js
$(element).on('your-event', function(){
  var audio = new Audio('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3');
  audio.play();
}
```

**But this way should work**

```js
var audio = new Audio('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3');
$(element).on('your-event', function(){
  audio.play();
}
```

Here is a working example on codepen: https://codepen.io/zecka/pen/VwjxGbE

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time, but is this not at all possible to play sound without user intervention?

Comment: But the user doesn't have to click on button to play sound.It is just a browser securtiy issue. If the user come on your webpage and he doesn't scroll or do anything the sound will never play. But if the user do anything on your page like "click somewhere" the sound can be played without other user interaction.
Check this example: https://robinferrari.ch/testaudio.html

Comment: my case is just like, you login to facebook and quickly minimize the screen. and then if some notification comes , it should play some sound

Comment: Yep but if you login to facebook that's meen that you interact with the document, so the conditions for playing an audio are met.

Comment: sorry my bad facebook is single page application but in my case login.html and home.html, so I minimized before redirecting to home page

Comment: In this case i think you have no working solution. otherwise popup can play audio without user interaction, it would be hell...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223983/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-zecka).